# Matthew/Luke Generations missing between Rahab and David

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, gospel-of-luke, chronology, genealogy, book-of-judges

While some people are interested in where the generations are different, my problem comes from where they are the same, to wit:

Boaz,
Obed,
Jesse,
David

Now Rahab is listed as the mother of Boaz. My understanding is that this is the same Rahab mentioned in the book of Joshua as the harlot of Jerico. If true, then both Matthew and Luke list only four generations covering the approximately 400 year period of the judges. There is no way (under normal circumstances) you get only four generations over that period of time unless you want to claim people were still regularly living 200-300 years during this time.

In fact, my NKJV claims there were 11 generations during this time. So my question is: why would both Matthew and Luke fail to mention the 6-8 missing generations that must have occurred during the period of the judges? Small thing I know, but it has bugged me for years and I have never seen it addressed anywhere. TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My study bible (The NIV Study Bible by Zondervan) notes that it was a common ancient practice to "telescope" a genealogy -- i.e. to skip over generations when building the list.  In the introduction to 1 Chronicles (where you'll also find a number of "missing" generations in its numerous genealogies), it states:

> The most common type of fluidity in Biblical materials is telescoping,
>   the omission of names from the list.  Unimportant names are left out
>   in order to relate an individual to a prominent ancestor, or possibly
>   to achieve the desired number of names in the genealogy.

Another point to note is that the Hebrew and Greek words commonly rendered in English as "father" & "mother" and "son" & "daughter" did not always refer to the direct parent or the direct offspring of an individual.  Based on context they could and did refer to more distant ancestors or descendants.

In our own time, lacking knowledge of these ancient historical and literary conventions, we have a tendency to be overzealous in our literalism and create difficulties or contradictions where they don't exist.  It's similar to the way we assume an ancient history is presenting a purely sequential chronology of events, when in fact ancient authors would often organize their material out of time sequence to put interrelated or thematically-similar events together in the account.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with JDM-GBG and yourself: the genealogy here is telescoped, i.e. generations have been omitted, and this is common practice in the Scriptures.  Rather than repeat the work of Dr John Millam I will just refer you to his online article "The Genesis Genealogies - are they complete?" which looks at many genealogies in Scripture.  An especially interesting verse in this respect is Exodus 6:20, which can be compared with Numbers 3:27,28.  See also 1 Chronicles 6:1-3.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to comprehend without presuming any hidden generations by averaging them out to 150 years old each, for example, and assuming that Rahab was very old when she begat Boaz(e.g. Rahab(70) + Boaz(150) + Obed(150) + Jesse(150) = David).

Comment: I don't think so. First at that time generations didn't live much past 70-80 years (look at the ages listed in Kings and Chronicles) so that would be a major stretch for one generation, let alone four. Second one must also account for the fact that a woman must be at a certain age before being able to conceive which maybe adds at least 45 or so years to your calculus plus having Rahab conceive at 70 is asking a lot. Finally, you would think a line of individuals who is living roughly twice the average would have had some mention of the fact somewhere. So it really seems implausible to me.

Comment: The problem however is that you are not considering the implications of your hypothesis of extra generations in this area of Jesus' genealogy. Such a theory not only requires you to hypothesize the reason for its omission by the writer of Matthew and Luke, but also the Old Testament itself(Ruth 4:18-22). If you can not provide a reasonable cause for its omission in this area of his genealogy(unlike for example Jehoiakim) then in the least you may not be giving this alternate interpretation fair consideration. Also Sarah conceived at 90, Gen. 17:17. If she were 100, they would average 147.

Comment: Also for the sake of comprehending the numbers I've submitted, I'll refer you to the [argument](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/29968/was-rahab-the-harlot-contemporary-with-salmon/29980#29980) on which they're based.

Comment: Also I wasn't saying that she lived to be 70 and then begat Boaz; I was saying that 70 years may have passed since she was at least twenty years old at the battle of Jericho, meaning she would have been 90 when she begot Boaz.

Comment: Furthermore, in my other answer I was kind of rounding up to 520 between Jericho and David so I could get a round number average of 150 for each; since the actual total between them is 515 however, the average ends up at 148(if she were 90) and 145(if she were 100).

Comment: I think also the claim that such should be discounted on the basis of improbable length of age, should consider the lengths of ages of those that lived long after the period of Judges, primarily Jehoiada who in the time of Joash king of Judah lived to be 130 years old(2Ch 24:15). Other examples include Job(140 - Job 42:16), of which there is evidence post-dated the Exodus(Job 22:22) and David(Job 5:15-16 from Psa 107:41-42); also Daniel(~ 131, Dan 1:1-5 to 9:1[~111 years] + if he were 20 years old in Dan 1) and Ezekiel(~ 118, Eze 1:1-2 till after Daniel[Eze 14:12-14], if 20 yr old in Ezek. 1).

Comment: You make some good points but I am looking at it statistically. Aside from Job, who appears to be pre-exodus, only Jehoida is anywhere near those ages you mentioned. While 1 person living that long is an outlier, 4 individuals in succession would be an extremely unlikely event, especially considering David and his generations immediately thereafter lived far shorter lives. it doesn't fit statistically.

Comment: In my last example I assume that Daniel was dead(he was being called righteous on par with Noah and Job); yet if he was somehow alive at the time, and assuming Ezekiel 14:21 were even partially referent to the Babylonian captivity(and not purely eschatological), then because it should seem plausible that 14:22-23 would also have been partially referent to the end of the post-captivity, as recorded in Ezra 7:6-8, then Ezekiel could still be argued to have been alive after Darius, that is, in the seventh of year of Artaxerxes II, to see their return(14:22-23), or older than I stated(~118+6+7).

Comment: @user21676, could you explain the difficulty with an ancient writer simply supplying an abbreviated genealogy, highlighting well-known individuals, vs. an exhaustive list of every person in the line?  Even in ancient times, people understood the idea of editorial efficiency -- leaving out information that's not relevant or necessary to the purpose of what they were writing. Exhaustive genealogies were undoubtedly kept somewhere (and Ezra 2:62 indicates that many such records were lost), but the inspired scriptures had -- and have -- other much more important purposes than mere family history.

Comment: I actually do resort to Ezra 2:62 in certain cases, sometimes as a direct reason(Jehoiakim, Cainaan), others as one of several possible valid interpretations(e.g. Meriaoth of 1Chr 9:11 vs 1Chr 6:8). Whether it may be used here, it seems not entirely obvious. I do think that if an alternate plausible explanation exists it should at least be considered. I think also that what is missing in that proposal is structure; while it can say for certain that there were some people put between Salmah and David, it can't say whether it were more so between Salmah and Obed, or Obed and Jesse, for example.

Comment: I will also grant that a 'telescoping' genealogy might be seen in Ezra 7:1-5(reverse chronology), where in verse 2 the writer of Ezra appears to skip Ahimaaz through Zadok 2 as recorded in 1 Chr. 6:8-12(and the Chronicler skips Azariah 1[1Ch 6:7]); but these are case examples whereby one is shown to be missing names on the basis of another account that contains them; not so here.

Comment: @user21676, given the fact that telescoped genealogies are known to exist (and are cited by biblical scholars as a common practice), it comes down then to the question of which hypothesis is more credible:  telescoped genealogy here in the lineage of David, or a sequence of multiple generations where people were alive and fathering children at ages in the 140-150 range.  The first hypothesis is far more credible to me; even among your many examples there wasn't one post-Exodus individual who lived older than 130.  (Job, by all accounts I've seen, lived long before the time of Moses.)

Comment: Matthew 1:5 seems to say exactly who Boaz' parents were and who Obed's parents were. So the only place to put extra generations would seem to be between Obed and Jesse, but this would mean that Matthew in the middle of giving one to one correspondence, jumped several generations to get to Jesse, and then went back to one generation with David. This same kind of round about reasoning would then have to be applied to Ruth 4:18-22. It is for this reason then that I favor believing they lived for long periods of time; otherwise it seems to introduce a temporal inconsistency in Jesus' genealogy.

Comment: @user21676, but that would make them fully consistent. The lineages in Ruth, in Matthew, and even in 1 Chronicles 2:11-14, would all have telescoping in one place:  between Obed & Jesse.  Why would they do this?  Because "everyone knew" who Obed was from the historical account of Ruth, and likewise "everyone knew" Jesse as the father of King David.  Any generations in between could be skipped because they weren't significant. The bigger and more troublesome inconsistency would be a reappearance of patriarchal-era lifespans at a time when Moses' 120 years was remarkable and David died at 70.